# Integer factorization: Single solution for integer equation

Tags: algorithms, factoring

While working on my [integer factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) project, I came to this:

$(A + CX)(B + CY) = D$

- $X,Y,A,B,C,D$ Are integer numbers
- $A,B,C,D > 0$
- $X,Y >= 0$
- $A,B,X,Y < C < D$
- If $X=Y$ than $Y > 0$ to avoid trivial solutions where $X = Y = 0$

What assignment of $A,B,C,D$ will provide only one solution for $X,Y$?

It looks like [Diophantine equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) can be handy here. But I do not know how to apply it.

**I am not looking for example but for patterns.**

Here is an example for such case:
$A=7;B=3;C=10;D=391$
$(7 + 10X)(3 + 10Y)=391$
The only solution here is: $X=1;Y=2$

Comment: Take $A, B$ arbitrary, $C$ satisfying $\max\{A,B\}<C<AB$.  Then set $D=AB$ and again $X=Y=0$ is the unique solution.

Comment: @vadim123 Nice one! I added another qualification to avoid those cases.

Comment: Okay, look, that's twice I've solved your problem, and twice you've changed it.  I will solve it one more time, and that's it.

Comment: Take $A=1, B=2, C=3, D=5$.  Then $X=1, Y=0$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $D$ arbitrary, let $A=1$, $B=1$, $C=D-1$. Then the only solution is $X=0$, $Y=1$.

Comment: This is correct, how ever it's pretty trivial solution. Take a look on my example. Those are the cases that I am after.

Comment: I doubt that you are going to find any pattern that isn't trivial. Individual examples, sure --- but you don't want those.